# Query has no destination for result data

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

My question is two fold. First, I have to evaluate the version of PostgreSQL in order to run the correct query. I have some servers running PostgreSQL 8.* and they have issues with using `DO` in my query below. The servers I have running 9.* (mostly I use a 9.2 server) are giving me an error "query has no destination for result data", when all I want is a print out of the select statement.

My query:

```
DO
$BODY$
BEGIN
IF (SELECT setting from pg_settings where name = 'server_version') >= '9.2' THEN
    SELECT pg_database.datname AS Database_Name, pg_authid.rolname AS Database_Owner, 
    pg_authid.rolsuper AS IsSuperUser, pg_tablespace.spcname AS TableSpaceName, 
    pg_catalog.pg_tablespace_location(pg_tablespace.oid) AS TableSpaceLocation
    FROM pg_database
    JOIN pg_authid on pg_database.datdba = pg_authid.oid
    CROSS JOIN pg_tablespace
    WHERE datistemplate = false
    AND pg_database.dattablespace = pg_tablespace.oid;
ELSE
    SELECT pg_database.datname AS Database_Name, pg_authid.rolname AS Database_Owner, 
    pg_authid.rolsuper AS IsSuperUser, pg_tablespace.spcname AS TableSpaceName, pg_tablespace.spclocation AS TableSpaceLocation
    FROM pg_database
    JOIN pg_authid on pg_database.datdba = pg_authid.oid
    CROSS JOIN pg_tablespace
    WHERE datistemplate = false
    AND pg_database.dattablespace = pg_tablespace.oid;
END IF;
END;
$BODY$
```

So, if `DO` doesn't work pre-9.0 and I'm getting the error post 9.0 I'm kinda stuck on what I can do to satisfy both conditions.

Comment: Use PERFORM instead of SELECT

Comment: You may either test the server version in the client before submitting the query (thus avoiding the `DO` construct), or create your own `pg_tablespace_location` function on the 8.x servers in a way that the same query will work on all server versions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DO` statement cannot return or output any data. The [manual page for `DO`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-do.html) describes it thus:

> The code block is treated as though it were the body of a function with no parameters, returning void.

Note that a function here is not like a stored procedure in other DBMS's: you cannot "output" a result set half-way through the function, but must explicitly return some particular value. To get a result set, you define the return type as `SETOF` something, and can then run `SELECT * FROM some_set_returning_function('some_param');`

Additionally, the `DO` statement was only added in Postgres 9.0, so testing for earlier versions inside such a statement is, as you have found, not going to work.

What you will need to do is either shift the procedural logic (the `IF`) into the calling application, or write a complete [pl/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql.html) function for all or part of your query. If you make it return a `SETOF RECORD` you can use [`RETURN QUERY SELECT ...`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpgsql-control-structures.html) and put the whole query inside the body of the function. If you need to support Postgres 8.2 or lower, you will need to use a loop and `RETURN NEXT` instead.

Incidentally, note that PostgreSQL folds column names to lowercase on output unless explicitly quoted, so for instance `TableSpaceLocation` will return to your application as `tablespacelocation`. I would strongly recommend you use all-lowercase underscore-separated identifiers throughout to avoid confusion, e.g. `table_space_location`. If you must preserve case, use double quotes to escape the exact string, e.g. `"TableSpaceLocation"`; this is then treated as a distinct identifier from the unquoted or all-lower-case version.